# How did the Klingon race acquire cloaking technology?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, cloaking

I was wondering how a *warrior race* like the Klingons managed to acquired such an advanced technology, for the Star Trek universe, as cloaking?

Comment: Even Klingons have scientists, you know.

Comment: @Brian Ortiz: Romulans have scientists as well, but they also acquire large amounts of tech via spying. So, what is your point?

Comment: @mbx I think Brian was addressing the inherent racism in this question.  "How did *Klingons* manage to *acquire* cloaking?"  Klingons are people too!  When you cut them, do they not bleed?

Comment: In the finale of Voyager, it was also a Klingon scientist that created the time machine that future Janeway used to go back and give advanced technology to the "present" Janeway in the Delta Quadrant.  So just because you're tough, doesn't mean your not smart.  ;)

Comment: A better question would be why the Klingons would sneak around cloaked like Romulan cowards, instead of approaching the enemy openly?  Where is the honor in that?! Of course this question would be off topic here... :(

Comment: It's also worth noting that cloaking isn't THAT high-tech for the Star Trek universe.  The Federation has demonstrated that they're capable of cloaking tech, in fact they have been for decades.  They don't use it because of a treaty with the Romulans, not because it's too advanced for them.

Comment: In Unexpected (ST:ENT) Klingons get holideck tecknology while the federation gets cloaking.

Comment: @Dima In the DS9 episode when the Klingons are mining the space outside of Bajoran territory, I think it is O'Brien that states mines aren't very honorable, to which Worf responds that nothing is more honorable than victory. The cloaking device is simply a means to help ensure victory.

Comment: @Dima - honour is all relative - to have honour you have to have a code of honour. If your code of honour allows the use of cloaking then cloaking you can use. To the Klingons, presumably, a cloak is simply another asset in their armoury, not unlike armour or even disruptors. Using money on the other hand...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Klingons received the technology in exchange for some battle cruisers from the Romulans around 2268, when the two civilizations shared a political alliance (both [startrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/cloaking-device-klingon) and the [ST:TNG Technical Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671704273) state this).

In TOS:"The Enterprise Incident" - caught in the Neutral Zone, the Enterprise was surrounded by a mixed pack of Romulan warbirds and [what appeared to be] Klingon D7 cruisers (one being the commanding vessel).  Spock noted that Star Fleet suspected the Romulans to be using Klingon designed ships, but did not know why because the D7 had no clear advantage over the Romulan warbird ... unless it also was adaptable to the cloaking device [first encountered in TOS:"Balance Of Terror"].

In the animated series episode [The Time Trap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0832430/), the Klingon vessel *Klothos* (captained by the famous [Captain Kor](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kor)) uses the cloak in the Battle of Caleb IV; as this was 2269, it's likely the earliest mention of Klingons making use of the technology.

[Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cloaking_device) has more information about cloaking technology in the Star Trek universe.

Comment: So it was only after 2268 that the Romulans utilized Klingon D-7 battle cruisers?

Comment: I had heard, out-of-universe, it was after someone had broken the warbird model.

Answer (score -2):

in the past there was an exchange of technology ,200 d-7 klingon decommisioned
battle cruisers in exchanged for cloaking techology the romulans had only impulse
powered warbirds since the plasma torpedoes took up so much power the KRd-7 klingon bodies with plasma torpedoes installed the warp technology could handle the plasma torpedoes and cloaking devices the klingons reversed engineered the cloaking device so as to cloak ships problem is klingons thought bigger was better
so the power requirement became to little up to the bigger ships 
so the klingons developed the br'el scout ship bird of prey the next in line was 
the greater bird of prey and finally the great warbird br'en same ship only 3 different sizes the romulans tried to use the ka'tinga but grew out of favor because it was obselete after a while and kept the remember they had time to develop the romulan warbird dedriex class the green 1 that we are familiar with

Comment: Was this in one of the novels?

Comment: Was this in one sentence? :O